# Написание кода одновременно с дебагом

Tags: python, отладка, pycharm, отладчик

Можно ли писать код и сразу же отправлять его в дебагер в PyCharm?

Например, есть код с точкой останова на `print(42)`:

```
# ...
print(42) # breakpoint here
# end of file
```

Я хочу запустить этот скрипт в дебаге, остановиться на строке `print(42)` и продолжить писать код ниже с возможностью его пошагового дебага, не перезапуская дебагер. То есть написал новую строку и сразу же могу сделать step into в неё.

Зачем? В начале скрипта долго читаются несколько больших файлов сложной структуры, поэтому хочется поставить точку останова после их прочтения и писать дальше код, чтобы: 1) не грузить их каждый раз, перезапуская скрипт в дебаге; 2) всегда видеть их структуру в дебаг окне переменных.

Comment: Не о том, что вы спрашиваете, но может быть полезно, Уже подготовленный массив данных (не важно какой тип объектов) можно сохранить с помощью встроенного модуля pickle. В этом формате его можно будет быстро подгружать во время разработки, не читая каждый раз эти сложные файлы.

Comment: @Alpensin я так и делаю, даже с компрессией, но всё равно медленно. Там модели машинного обучения гигабайтные

Comment: Разве что писать в jupyter notebook, или в научном режиме в PyCharm Professional.

Comment: @insolor а что за научный режим?

Comment: @стас https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html

Comment: Гигабайтные модели данных в IDE подгружать - это изврат. Неужели нет возможности загрузить только часть данных и отрабатывать пайплайн с ними? А все гигабайты данных лучше потом уже чистым питоном грузить и обрабатывать, а если нужно что-то знать о процессе, то писать эти сведения на экран или в лог.

Comment: @CrazyElf да, в принципе можно выделить только часть и сохранить отдельно для разработки. Так и сделаю, если нельзя по-другому